# In GHC, is there a way to print the exports of module?

Tags: haskell

If I want to see what exports there are from Test.QuickCheck, for example, is there a command I can issue to GHCI to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Typing `:browse Test.QuickCheck` (or whatever module you want) will print all the exports:

```
Prelude> :browse Test.QuickCheck
(.&.) ::
  (Testable prop1, Testable prop2) => prop1 -> prop2 -> Property
(==>) :: (Testable prop) => Bool -> prop -> Property
(><) :: (Gen a -> Gen a) -> (Gen a -> Gen a) -> Gen a -> Gen a
class Arbitrary a where
  arbitrary :: Gen a
  shrink :: a -> [a]

... <snip> ...

vectorOf :: Int -> Gen a -> Gen [a]
whenFail :: (Testable prop) => IO () -> prop -> Property
whenFail' :: (Testable prop) => IO () -> prop -> Property
within :: (Testable prop) => Int -> prop -> Property
```

For a complete list of GHCi commands, check [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).